# iframe and twitter javascript widget are not showing in wordpress post page

Tags: javascript, wordpress, twitter, widget, facebook-iframe

I have facebook iframe and twitter javascript widget inside a Wordpress post page.
Everything is showing with no problems. but when the other post editor just "View" or click on "Edit" from the wordpress dashboard on that post, the facebook iframe will be completely gone and the twitter widget will be missing lots of its code and followed by something like this ∓..........

I don't see the  tag at all only some of the content in the middle of the tags and the rest missing.

This is very strange, and it happens only when the other Post Editor views or click on Edit it happens like this. When i do it myself by pasting the code into the text tab of Wordpress i get not problem, once the person view thats draft post, it removes the iframe and mess with javascript.

The persons's web browser javascript is enabled and it is very strange and i want to find a solution.